# appcompat-v7 sources missing in the android repository

Tags: java, android

In SDK Manager there is a position named:
"Android Support Repository"

In that I can find a jar sources for the libraries like cardview, like support-v4, as well as javadoc jar files. However, in some of the projects, like appcompat or gridlayout there is no sources jar file, or javadoc file.

I was wondering why is that, and also if there is other place where I can get the newest (ver 21.0.0) sources for both? The official android git repository does not contain new java files (for example there is no ActionBarDrawerToggle java file, as well as many others).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sources for appcompat-v7 are available within "API21/Sources for Android SDK" package which can be downloaded with SDK Manager, the path is `\sdk\sources\android-21\android\support\v7\`

Android Studio will allow you to browse lib source code when you point this dir as appcompat-v7 source dir root.

Comment: @Lucas You can change accepted answer, as it is now more accurate. Regards!

Comment: How do you point Android Studio to the source folder when the library is added through a `compile` directive in a Gradle project?

Comment: @Nilzor when I navigate from my code to appcompat source, by default Android Studio shows decompiled signature of class (just method names, without body). On top of source window there is a yellow bar with "Sources not found/attach sources". Click button, point dir from my answer and you are good to go.

Comment: Where are the style and theme xml files for the library though?

Answer (score 3):

The source for the v21 versions of the support libraries will be released alongside the source of Android 5.0 coinciding with the start of OTAs to Nexus devices (i.e., early November).

Comment: The source from the second revision is now available at [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/android-5.0.0_r2/v7/appcompat/](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/android-5.0.0_r2/v7/appcompat/)

Comment: Jan 2015 update: Still not a part of the Android Support Repository :-( Google please fix! Sources and Javadoc are an important piece of documentation that helps in everyday development when you're using an IDE such as AS.

Comment: @Nilzor please see my answer, you can get appcompat sources using SDK Manager.

Comment: I appreciate that but it's still not a part of the Android Support **Repository** (Maven compatible folder structure under /sdk/extras/google/m2repository), which stops one from importing it automatically in a gradle project